# Facebook Like Box width of sharing box when clicked on

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-like

I've added the HTML 5 version of the Facebook like box to our site.

However when you actually press the button the box which is normally 450 pixels wide is showing only as 49 pixels wide.

This means when you press it, you can't actually share it :(

Example image below:

[image]

Live example here: http://understandinge.com/3-days-to-go/

Any ideas what is causing this? I've tried the overflows and widths etc and got nowhere :(

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe that facebook gennerates has a max-width:100% applied to it from your css. Since the span parent of that iframe has a width of 47px, the iframe max-width is 100% of the parent element its contained in- 47px. This max-width overrides the width property.

I unchecked max-width:100% in developer tools and it shows up. (Although, the background is transparent). I hope this helps!

Comment: Howdy, yea that was it! No idea on the transparency issue. At least they can actually see the box now :)